# Different indentation in VSCode in the same project

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I've always worked in VSCode indenting either with spaces or tabs, but with a size of 3 or more. But, currently, I'm working on a project where everything is configured to work in a size of 2. My issue is I really struggle to read with that size, I can barely identify each line of code and indentations, even with the visual guides that VSCode gives, and it is super uncomfortable to work in this way. I guess I have some visual impairment.

Is there an easy way, to work on a size of 3 or more for development purposes, but keep the files of the project in their original size? I'm looking just for a visual solution.

I couldn't find anything related, the only thing that I can think of now is every time I merge my changes, change the Prettier config, and format everything again, but I guess this could create issues for the maintenance of the repository.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a VSCode extension called `stretchy-spaces`, maybe it will solve your problem

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kylepaulsen.stretchy-spaces

Comment: I didn't know this extension, it worked great! Thanks for the help.